# Mongoose query to pull data between two datetimes

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mLab db set up and interacting with it through Mongoose. I want to query the db and return all records within a 10 min window. So at the time of the query, it will look at the date field and bring back all records within 10 min before the current datetime and within 10 min after the current datetime.

A db entry looks like this :

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("572cd34786d87203006a89dc"), 
  "expecting" : "Chris", 
  "channel" : "D164Z16BB", 
  "date" : ISODate("2016-05-06T13:30:00Z"), 
  "userId" : "U0GMSLZ7C", 
  "email" : "email@gmail.com", 
  "userName" : "userName", 
  "firstName" : "Bob", 
  "__v" : 0 
}
```

My query looks like :

```
var now = new Date();
var later = moment(now).add(15, 'm').toDate();
var earlier = moment(now).subtract(15, 'm').toDate();

Schedules.find({
    'date': {
       '$gte': earlier,
       '$lte': later
     }
}, function(err, schedules) {
    if(err) res.send(err);
      res.json(schedules);
});
```

Even when there is an entry in the db that meets the time criteria, it is not returning anything.

Post request :

```
apiRouter.post('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    var schedule = new Schedules();

    schedule.firstName = req.body.firstName;
    schedule.real_name = req.body.real_name;
    schedule.userName = req.body.userName;
    schedule.email = req.body.email;
    schedule.userId = req.body.userId;
    schedule.date = req.body.date;
    schedule.channel = req.body.channel;
    schedule.expecting = req.body.expecting;

    schedule.save(function(err, schedule) {
        if (err) res.send(err);
        res.json({message: 'Schedule was created'});
    });
});
```

Comment: You can set mongoose Debug **true**, that way you will see what query is fired.

Comment: @anwerjunaid this is the debug I get : schedules.find({ date: { '$gte': new Date("Fri, 06 May 2016 14:15:36 GMT"), '$lte': new Date("Fri, 06 May 2016 14:45:36 GMT") } }) { fields: undefined }

Comment: Check the answer, it might help

Comment: @anwerjunaid that debug has the code modified based on the answer

Comment: I will update my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error ended up being when I was saving the date. It was saving an EST time as UTC instead of converting it from EST to UTC. So the query itself was working as it should have been since it was using the correct times and there was a non-converted time saved in the DB

Comment: can you please let me know how can i check if my dates of mongoose are in UTC or not...?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is you problem,

```
 var now = new Date(); 
 var later = moment(now).add(15, 'm').toDate();
 var earlier = moment(now).subtract(15, 'm').toDate();
```

**toDate** returns object and mongodb may have string.

Use this instead.

```
 var later = moment().add(15, 'm').format();
 var earlier = moment().subtract(15, 'm').format();
```

Or you can set schema to date.

You data is in different format than what you searching for.

```
"date": {
    "$date": "2016-05-06T10:00:00.000Z"
},
```

This is wrong entry. You should always have something like this

```
"date" : ISODate("2016-04-24T04:50:07Z"),
```

This can we done , when you pass date object properly.

Now if you really want this structure only , you will have to change your query to something like this.

```
{
    'data.$date' : {
                   //gte,
                   //lte
                   }
}
```

Comment: That didn't make a difference. I posted the debug in the comments. And this is my schema : 
var ScheduleSchema = new Schema({
    firstName : String,
    real_name : String,
    userName : String,
    email : String,
    userId : String,
    date : Date,
    channel: String,
    expecting : String
});

Comment: When I save the date to the db do I need to save it as an ISODate?

Comment: No you just pass **Date Object** or **Date String**, mongoose will handle it as schema is set to **Date**

Comment: Also your **_id** should not look like this. There is something wrong with your update/insert method.

Comment: I just added my post request

Comment: Everything seems fine, please check the collection in mongo shell and try to fire the same query there. Also check the result of db.schedule.find(), to see the format of data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111236/discussion-between-erichardson30-and-anwerjunaid).